# How can I drop a PostgreSQL table with double quotes in its name?

Tags: postgresql

I've inadvertedly created the following table, which I can't remove:

```
db=> \dt
                        List of relations
 Schema |       Name          | Type  | Owner     
--------+---------------------+-------+---------------
 public | "dm"."feedbacks"    | table | write
```

What is the right DROP TABLE string to delete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgress allows you to use 2 consecutive double quotes characters to escape a double quote inside a string - so i think your DROP command will look like this:

`DROP TABLE """dm"".""feedbacks"""`